# Grails Embed images in csv and xml

Tags: xml, image, grails, csv, groovy

is there anyway to have thumbnail image 50x50 in csv and xml? I'm using grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the image to Base64 and embed the byte data.  This is sometimes done in css and other mediums like databases.  Here is a simple example...

encoding an image to CSV file...

```
def csvFile = new File('my_csv.csv');  
def imageFile = new File('./images/thumbnail.png');    
String imageData = imageFile.bytes.encodeBase64().toString();

csvFile.append("${image.name}, ${imageData}"); //<-- write image name and data
```

decoding the image is also easy...

```
byte[] imageBytes = imageData.decodeBase64();
imageFile = new File('./images/decoded/thumbnail.png');
imageFile.setBytes(imageBytes);
```